# MVC C# - Sending multiple List in Json format

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, list

Below is the Code which gets data from data layer :-

I want to send these 3 lists in Json format. How to bundle this is one Array?

```
public JsonResult getDataAll()
        {

            List<Chart> data1 = dashboard.CountbyDep();
            List<Chart> data2 = dashboard.CountbyDes();
            List<Chart> data3 = dashboard.CountbyCat();

            allData = // ??

            return Json(allData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

If i send only `data1` then it goes successfully. How to send 3 lists?

Comment: You could send it as an Array of IEnumerable?

Comment: join three list to a single one and send

Comment: @kumarch1 I want 3 different lists in JSON, if i send all as one then i cannot differentiate in the Jquery Object Model... So an Array will do...`Array[0]` will contain data1, `Array[1]` data2 and so on..

Comment: Keep a pointer to each list (if it is json then it would be like {p1:[{...}],p2:[{...}],p3[{...}]}) then differentiate through the pointer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
List<Chart> data1 = dashboard.CountbyDep();
List<Chart> data2 = dashboard.CountbyDes();
List<Chart> data3 = dashboard.CountbyCat();
List<List<Chart>> allData = new List<List<Chart>>
{
  data1, data2, data3
};

return Json(allData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```